# Is it true that choosing between "would be" and "is" sometimes doesn't change the overal meaning of an excerpt?

Tags: grammar

His former friend wouldn't have left him to die. **It is/would be just too heartless.** Even a monster would have a second thought. His former friend wasn't like him, this dude, this monster!

I think It would be just too heartless would be better; however, regardless of what tense you choose, I don't think it changes the meaning by much? Am I wrong? Also, is there a set of general rules that dictate what tense you should use in a given context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the two can be taken in the same way, the difference in wording generally leads to subtly different meanings.

---

> His former friend wouldn't have left him to die. It **is** just too heartless.

This says that the act of leaving somebody to die is heartless. It refers to the act in general and would apply to *anybody* leaving *anyone* to die.

Because it *is* heartless, it's something that is true regardless of whether or not his former friend actually did it or not.

---

> His former friend wouldn't have left him to die. It **would be** just too heartless.

This can have a more specific meaning, referring to it being heartless for *his former friend* to leave *him* to die.

In other words, it applies to the specific set of circumstances (his former friend, whoever *he* is, and whatever the situation is), rather than to leaving people to die in general.

Since it's conditional, the statement is only true *if* his former friend did it.

---

If you want to make a statement about leaving people to die in general, then use *is*. But if you are making a statement about the particular situation (which may or may not have happened), then use *would be*.